# TrigExpand not grouping terms

Tags: trigexpand

Why does `TrigExpand[Cos[a+b]]` return the familiar and expected

`Cos[a] Cos[b] - Sin[a] Sin[b]`

but `TrigExpand[Cos[2 Pi n x + b]]` return

`Cos[b] Cos[n \[Pi] x]^2 - 2 Cos[n \[Pi] x] Sin[b] Sin[n \[Pi] x] -  Cos[b] Sin[n \[Pi] x]^2`?

I would have thought that *Mathematica* would group the terms into a single constant.

I can of course perform `TrigExpand[Cos[a+b]] /. a -> 2 Pi n x`,

but that seems rather inelegant.

Comment: From the `Details` section: ```TrigExpand splits up sums and integer multiples that appear in arguments of trigonometric functions, and then expands out products of trigonometric functions into sums of powers, using trigonometric identities when possible. ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the `2`. Compare

```
TrigExpand[Cos[a + b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With

```
 TrigExpand[Cos[2 a + b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is because

```
TrigExpand[Cos[2 a]]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using your original expression, if you remove the `2` now you get what you expected

```
 TrigExpand[Cos[Pi  n  x + b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Having the `2` in there made it use that intermediate rule which caused the output to look completely different now. There is probably a way to turn off that rule for `Cos[2 x]` from expanding.

At the risk of breaking something internal, you can modify `TrigReduce` to change only the case when `Cos[2 x]` is in play:

```
Unprotect[TrigExpand];
TrigExpand[Cos[2*x_ + y_]] := Cos[2*x]  Cos[y] - Sin[2*x]  Sin[y]
Protect[TrigExpand];
```

and now

```
TrigExpand[Cos[2  Pi  n  x + b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh.  How interesting (and unintuitive).  And it "works" when you try `TrigExpand[Cos[2. Pi n x + b]]` (note the 2.).  Thanks ($\checkmark$).